# Float div left and div centered without overlapping on resize

Tags: css, positioning, css-float, html, resize

I'm looking to have a div aligned left (Div 1) and a div aligned center (Div 2).

When the user resizes the window, the centered div (Div 2) should stay centered until it bumps into the edge of Div 1.
Div 2 (centered div) should not always be docked left unless the width of Div 1 (left div) plus half the width of Div 2 is greater than half the browser width.

Any thoughts on making this happen without javascript?

[image: Example as image]

Here is a working example to work from: http://jsfiddle.net/pjg8D/9/

```
<div id="fixedBar">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>


<!-- http://i42.tinypic.com/iqv5tu.jpg -->
```

```
#fixedBar {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f99;       

}

#div1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
    float: left;
}

#div2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the question is to use `min-width` on the container div. The ratio for this width is calculated as follows: ( Div1 Width + half of Div2's Width ) x 2.

The solution is here: http://jsfiddle.net/pjg8D/16/

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the left hand div a `%` width, then give the right hand div a `left-margin` of the same `%`. Try this:

```css
#div1 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
    float: left;
}

#div2 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 0 0 25%;
    background: blue;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pjg8D/13/)

Comment: just to be more clear with my original question. The centered div needs to stay centered until it bumps the edge of div 1. Div 2 (centered div) should not always be docked left unless the width of div 1 (left div) is greater than half the browser width + half the width of div 2.

Comment: Ah, you'll need javascript for that then, as there will be some calculation required to check the width of the left div, whilst maintaining the central alignment of the right div.

Comment: That's what I assumed at first but then if you resize this page, the whole Stack Overflow centered container will stay centered until it bumps the left edge, then it begins "overflow". That makes me question if it's possible with just CSS.

Comment: That's because the container div of the website has `min-width` set on it.